# Interseting question regarding a variant of vernier calipers

Tags: units

So our professor asked us to come up with interesting questions on vernier calipers as he taught us about them today.
Obviously I could have Googled some up and gave it to him however for my own sake I wanted to do some thought.

What came to my mind was whether I could create a triple vernier caliper? I.e., a vernier caliper with 3 scales and use it to measure lengths more accurately and to more significant figures.

Idea looked interesting and a question for this would be highly conceptual based but fun to solve and even make, could anyone point me in the right direction about how this would work or would it even work, etc.

I would love to come up with a question where you have to find the general formula to find the reading of such a triple vernier caliper.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you would like the capability of a slide rule incorporated into your caliper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule

Answer (score 1):

The working principle for the caliper is that the human eye can see the precise matching up of two marking lines more accurately than it can judge a position between two markings. So in fact, because the presence of symmetry is easier to judge than the precise amount of departure from symmetry, or put differently: zero detection is easier than measuring absolute magnitudes.

This fact is often used in technology, for instance by constructing differential amplifiers that can measure small signals more accurately than single-ended ones. But unfortunately it is difficult to use this advantage more than once. The ability of the eye to see accurate lining up of marking lines will not be increased by looking at the *difference* in lining up, if you just provide multiple lining up situations at different places in the viewing field. Just like triple-differential measurements - or amplifiers -  will not immediately give you more accuracy than working just differential.

What may come closest to your proposal is the use of repeated inversions in time, like a "chopping amplifier" where the two input terminals are swapped periodically. This does cancel out most of the mismatch and makes it more sensitive to measure differences. So we then use time as the extra dimension.

Likewise, you could (optically, perhaps) provide the eye with a view of marking lines that should match up and where the image is alternately mirrored, say every second. That's a bit like  how astronomers would compare night-sky pictures in the old days. Here it might make the detection more sensitive, meaning you can start with a finer vernier to begin with, and get a more sensitive total system. You will have to try to find out...

Comment: Yes it would be quite hard to implement however that is not my point, my point was whether i could pose a paragraph based question on this concept and this would be a highly conceptual question and a fun one to solve for students as well as a hard question